# How to convert LTR(left to right) properties and values in a CSS file to RTL counterparts and vice-versa

Tags: php, css, right-to-left

I have many CSS files that are made for websites which are left-to-right

I want to create a php function that can convert the LTR properties and values to their RTL counterparts

The reason why I want to do this is because the website is always under development and it have tens of pages and css files and it's very hard to keep track on all of them

The purpose of this function is to automatically convert CSS files, so it would be easier to make RTL version of the website

For example:

```
// This is the content of the css file:
$content = '
html, body {
  direction: ltr;
}
#element1 {
  padding:   1px 2px  3px 4px;
  margin-right: 3em;
  background-position: 5%   80%;
  background-image: url(image.png);
  cursor: ne-resize;
  text-align: left; /* 1 */
}
#element2 {
  background: url(image.gif) 5% 80%;
  text-align: right; /* 2 */
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
';

$content = convertCSStoRTL($content);

// The output - This is what i want it to become after the function is applied to the content of the css file:
$content = '
html, body {
  direction: rtl;
}
#element1 {
  padding: 1px 4px 3px 2px;
  margin-left: 3em;
  background-position: 95% 80%;
  background-image: url(image.png);
  cursor: nw-resize;
  text-align: right; /* 1 */

}
#element2 {
  background: url(image.gif) 95% 80%;
  text-align: left; /* 2 */
  border-right:  1px solid #000;
}
';
```

How can I do that (in the easiest way) in PHP ?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to be in for a world of hurt if you try and rely on regular expressions/str_replace to modify your CSS.  My recommendation would be to have PHP generate 2 distinct files rather than taking one and generating its mirror, especially when you consider properties like borders instead of just alignment.

I haven't actually tested this, but it should give you an idea of how to approach it

```
<?php
$ltr = true;
function doLTR($left, $right, $property = FALSE) {
    @global $ltr;

    $direction = $ltr ? $left : $right;
    if (!$property) {
        print $direction;
    } else {
        print $direction . ': ' . $property;
    }
}
?>

.test {
    border: 1px solid;
    <?php doLTR('margin-left', 'margin-right', '10px'); ?>
    <?php doLTR('text-align: left', 'text-align: right'); ?>
}
```

If `$ltr = true`, you should in theory get this output:

```
.test {
    border: 1px solid;
    margin-left: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

If it is false (rtl), you would get this:

```
.test {
    border: 1px solid;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

It may be worth considering using a CSS Preprocessor like Sass or LESS to do this sort of grunt work for you, since that's what they do best.

Comment: Thanks for the fast replay :), but you didn't fully understand what I wanted, the way you did it in the replay will indeed going to be bringing me a world of hurt, although, regular expressions may be a very good idea, but I know only little RegEx, please check my answer again (i've updated the example) to understand what I meant, and if you could help me, I would be thankful :)

Comment: I would like to point out that you _did_ ask for the simplest solution.  RegExs generally take a lot of effort to decode down the road if you ever need to change them (especially if you're not very good with them), and you have to make sure you're not accidentally matching things that shouldn't be replaced (some people do strange things like have classes named `.sidebar-left` or have the words left or right in image filenames).

Answer (score 0):

The following SCSS import adds some useful variables, functions, and mixins.

[View on GitHub](https://github.com/tysonmatanich/directional-scss)

[Read more](http://www.matanich.com/2013/09/06/rtl-css-with-sass/)

```
// Override default value for $dir in directional.scss
$dir: rtl;

// Import helpers from directional.scss
@import "directional";

// Use the helpers to make CSS for LTR or RTL
body {
    text-align: $left;
    padding-#{$right}: 1em;
    margin: dir-values(0 2em 0 1em) if-ltr(!important);
}
```