# Convert left to right to right to left - input

Tags: html, css

I have written a code whose output is [What is] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BH8GP.png) and I want it to be [What should be] [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqzIu.png) How do I do this? Where should it be edited?

I have written a code whose output is [What is] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BH8GP.png) and I want it to be [What should be] [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqzIu.png) How do I do this? Where should it be edited?

```css
    .prt-pricing-detial {
        display: table;
        text-align: right;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
    .pricing-heading {
        font-family: "Mr Eaves XL Modern", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        line-height: normal;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #000000;
        vertical-align: middle;
        display: table-cell;

    }
    .pricing-profit {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        height: 42px;
        font-size: 18px;
        width: 120px;
        text-indent: 8px;
    }
    .prt-pricing-name {
        text-align:center;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 18px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
```

```html
       <div class="prt-pricing-content">
                            <div class="prt-pricing-name"><span></span></div>
                            <div class="prt-pricing-detial">
                              <span class="pricing-heading">سود شما:</span><div class="pricing-field">
                              <input class="pricing-profit" type="number" value="25.00" disabled="">
```

Comment: you just need to swap tags `span` and `input` in the `<div class="prt-pricing-detial">`

Comment: Please change the codes and reply Thank you @sergeykuznetsov

Comment: Try to add a runnable snippet to your question.  Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410792/how-to-convert-ltrleft-to-right-properties-and-values-in-a-css-file-to-rtl-cou https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56907889/css-right-to-left-keyframes-transform-100-to-transform-none https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52516820/automactially-set-direction-and-text-align-based-on-rtl-or-ltr-languages

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS `direction:rtl`.

```
.row-reverse {

        direction: rtl;

}
```

**`Direction`** property specifies the text direction/writing direction within a block-level element.
 **`Direction`** have a 4 value

`direction: ltr|rtl|initial|inherit;`

So I only give 2 for this problem

- ltr = *Text direction goes from left-to-right* - Default
- rtl = *Text direction goes from right-to-left*

Will get output like this

```css
.row-reverse {
    
            direction: rtl;
}

.prt-pricing-detial {
  display: table;
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.pricing-heading {
  font-family: "Mr Eaves XL Modern", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000000;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}

.pricing-profit {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 42px;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 120px;
  text-indent: 8px;
}

.prt-pricing-name {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="prt-pricing-content row-reverse">
  <div class="prt-pricing-name"><span></span></div>
  <div class="prt-pricing-detial">
    <span class="pricing-heading">سود شما:</span>
    <div class="pricing-field">
      <input class="pricing-profit" type="number" value="25.00" disabled="">
```